# Possibility to trigger request when request received by MockService

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm trying to automatically trigger a soapui request with a groovy script when my mockservice receives a request. The request to trigger is based on a different WSDL than the service.

if possible, how would I go about to achieve the above?

Sorry if this is a totally stupid question...

Comment: ok, but... what is the question?

Comment: is it possible? and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `TestSuite` for the `MockService` and the SoapUI `request` as a `TestStep`, you can run the test step by it's name in the `OnRequest` Script for the `MockService`

`testRunner.runTestStepByName("AnotherSoapRequest")`